# How to pass dynamic scope values in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this I created nested ng-repeat.Now I need to pass the first `ng-repeat` id value to the inner `ng-repeat`. How can I pass that `val.id` in inner `ng-repeat`

**My Table**

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="val in sample">
<td>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{val.id}}</td>
        <td>{{val.name}}</td>
     </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="new_val in new_sample{{val.id}}">
         <td>
             <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td>{{new_val .new_id}}</td>
                     <td>{{new_val .new_name}}</td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
         </td>
         </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**My Script**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("MyController", function MyController($scope){ 
    $scope.sample = [
        {'id' : '1','name' : 'jon'},
        {'id' : '2','name' : 'albert'}
    ];

    $scope.new_sample1 = [
        {'id' : '11','name' : 'jon1'},
        {'id' : '22','name' : 'albert1'}
    ];

    $scope.new_sample2 = [
        {'id' : '111','name' : 'jon2'},
        {'id' : '222','name' : 'albert2'}
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using `ng-init` in your ng-repeat element. In this case your HTML would be

```
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
<tr ng-repeat="val in sample" ng-init="subVal=new_sample[val.id]">
<td>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{val.id}}</td>
        <td>{{val.name}}</td>

     </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="new_val in subVal">
         <td>
             <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td>{{new_val.id}}</td>
                     <td>{{new_val.name}}</td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
         </td>
         </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And inside your script.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.controller("MyController", function MyController($scope){ 
     $scope.sample = [
     {'id' : '1','name' : 'jon'},
     {'id' : '2','name' : 'albert'}
     ]

     $scope.new_sample = {
         1 : [  
                 {'id' : '11','name' : 'jon1'},
                 {'id' : '22','name' : 'albert1'}
             ],
         2 : [
                 {'id' : '111','name' : 'jon2'},
                 {'id' : '222','name' : 'albert2'}
         ]

    }

     });
```

But please notice you need to change your new_sample object as mentioned above. A working [Feedel](https://jsfiddle.net/mkez8xhd/1/) is here

Answer (score 0):

You `ng-repeat` div should access array via its index & this could be doable on markup itself.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="new_val in ['new_sample'+ val.id]">
```

Comment: @Pravin does this helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use {{ }} for accessing the object name in ng-repeat. You are required to change the structure of your object in order to access them dynamically.

Here is it with little alteration.

```
 var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
 myApp.controller("MyController", function MyController($scope){ 
      $scope.sample = [
           {'id' : '1','name' : 'jon'},
           {'id' : '2','name' : 'albert'}
      ]

      $scope.innerSample = {
           "new_sample1" : [
                {'id' : '11','name' : 'jon1'},
                {'id' : '22','name' : 'albert1'}
           ],
           "new_sample2" : [
                {'id' : '111','name' : 'jon2'},
                {'id' : '222','name' : 'albert2'}
           ]  
      };
 });
```

HTML File

```
 <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="val in sample">
           <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{val.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{val.name}}</td>
                     </tr>
                          <tr ng-repeat="new_val in innerSample[newSample{{val.id}}]">
                              <td>
                                  <table>
                                      <tr>
                                          <td>{{new_val .new_id}}</td>
                                          <td>{{new_val .new_name}}</td>
                                      </tr>
                                   </table>
                              </td>
                         </tr>
                </table>
           </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```